# Extract Mobile from Text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

i have data with 4 mobile numbers and i want extract mobile numbers to separate columns

like i have data in column A with mobile numbers
i want to extract mobile numbers to separate 4 columns like column B and column C and column D and column E

I have applied this formula to extract it's not done

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID($A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},$A1&1234567890)),999))," ",REPT(" ",999)),999*(COLUMN(A1)-1)+1,999))
```

[image: See Image]

i want to extract like this below image

[image: See Image]

Comment: So it's either Excel 2007 or Excel 2016? Can you also post your data as markdown sampel data? If Excel 2016, you can use in `B1`: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")` dragged right and down.

Comment: applied not working  `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]["&COLUMN(A1)&"]")`

Comment: Then kindly remove Excel 2016 from the tags and rework your question to include markdown sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in `B1`, and drag the formula to the right and down.

```
=MID($A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,10))-1,$A1,FIND(A1,$A1)+10),"")),10)
```

***Note 1;*** it's an array-formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

***Note2;*** I assumed you'd have at least 10 characters before the 1st occurence of a phone number **and** not digits in your string other than those in your phone numbers.

Comment: Thankyou so much it's extracted all mobile numbers